# How to fix the security group attached to the EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

I can connect to AWS EC2 Instance using PuTTY at my home by laptop. But when I bring the laptop to some cafe that provides free Wifi, it ends up with timeout error.

In order to solve this problem, I need to fix the security group attached to the EC2 instance to allow the connection from the cafe’s public IP.

Unfortunately, I can not figure out what is an appropriate word to search for.
Please advise me where I should read and follow to fix this problem?
If it's possible, I want to see anything other than Amazon AWS official page, because it's difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Log in
2. Search for "VPC" in the search bar at the top
3. Click on VPC
4. Click on "security groups" on the left
5. Find your security group
6. Edit your security group

You can also get to this by navigating to the instance under the EC2 service, then clicking on the details panel and there'll be a link to the security group.

When you edit the security group, you can add 'my current ip address'. If you do this from the cafe it should work.